# Encoding a Huffman Binary tree

Tags: c++, binary-tree, huffman-code

I am trying to write a function that takes in a huffman tree and a character. It should then encode the character and return it.

**The code so far:**

```
string encode(NodePtr root, char letter)
{
    string encode_str; //a string which will store the encoded string
    NodePtr tempNode = root; //Initialize a new Huffman to be used in this function
    NodePtr tempLeft = root->left;
    NodePtr tempRight = root->right;

        //A while loop that goes on until we find the letter we want
        while((tempLeft->letter != letter) || (tempRight->letter != letter))
        {
         if((tempRight->is_leaf()) && (tempRight->letter == letter)) //check if is leaf and is letter
         {
                encode_str = encode_str + '1';
         }
         else if ((tempLeft->is_leaf()) && (tempLeft->letter == letter)) //check if is leaf and is letter
         {
             encode_str = encode_str + '0';
         }
         else if ((tempRight->is_leaf()) && (tempRight->letter != letter)) //check if is leaf and is NOT letter
         {
             tempNode = root->left;
             tempLeft = tempNode->left;
             tempRight = tempNode->right;
             encode_str = encode_str + '0';
         }
          else if ((tempLeft->is_leaf()) && (tempLeft->letter != letter)) //check if is leaf and is NOT letter
         {
             tempNode = root->right;
             tempLeft = tempNode->left;
             tempRight = tempNode->right;
             encode_str = encode_str + '1';
         }
         }    

    return encode_str;
}
```

This has not worked so far and debugging hasn't helped me either. Can anyone help me out here, or at least tell me if my thinking is right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If neither tempLeft nor tempRight is a leaf, you've got an infinite loop:

```
while((tempLeft->letter != letter) || (tempRight->letter != letter))
    {
        if((tempRight->is_leaf()) &&
           (tempRight->letter == letter)) 
        {
            // no
        }
        else if ((tempLeft->is_leaf()) &&
                 (tempLeft->letter == letter)) 
        {
            // no
        }
        else if ((tempRight->is_leaf()) && 
                 (tempRight->letter != letter)) 
        {
            // no
        }
        else if ((tempLeft->is_leaf()) && 
                 (tempLeft->letter != letter))
        {
            // no
        }
     }
```

There must be something you intend to do in the case where the nodes are not leaves. Maybe recurse?

(Per comments) You might be working with a variant of Huffman trees in which you can guarantee that every node is either a leaf or has one leaf child. If you can guarantee that, then the above does not matter (it would be good to throw an exception if it occurs). However, real-world Huffman trees do not have this property.

---

When one child is a leaf and the other is not your target letter, you attempt to set a new `tempNode`, `tempLeft` and `tempRight` for the next go around the loop.

```
    else if ((tempRight->is_leaf()) && 
             (tempRight->letter != letter)) 
     {
         tempNode = root->left;
         tempLeft = tempNode->left;
         tempRight = tempNode->right;
         encode_str = encode_str + '0';
     }
```

However, since you never modify `root`, `tempNode = root->left` will always set `tempNode` to the same node.

You probably want `tempNode = tempNode->left`.

---

To avoid repetition of code, you can move

```
tempLeft = tempNode->left;
tempRight = tempNode->right;
```

... to be the first thing that happens in the `while()` loop.

---

You say that debugging hasn't helped. Have you actually run it in a debugger?

Write a unit test that sets up your tree; validates that the tree actually contains what you intend it to; and calls this function with one letter. Decide how you think execution should proceed. Now run the code in a debugger, stepping through it. When it stops doing what you think it should, you'll be able to reason about why.

---

A common way to implement Huffman Encoding is to have an array of leaf nodes, so you can reach the node through simple array access:

```
    NodePtr nodeA = nodes[0];
```

... and have a pointer to the parent in each node, and a field indicating whether it's the left or right child, so that you can easily traverse the tree backwards, from leaf to root, building up a code (in reverse):

```
    string code = "";
    NodePtr node = nodeA;
    while(node->parent != NULL) {
        code = node->code + code; 
        node = node->parent;
    }
```

Comment: I thought root->left or root->right was always a leaf? I based it on that. So my plan was to check if it was leaf and see if the letter matched. If not it "goes down the path" of not leaf and tries again. Maybe add encode(tempNode,letter) if != letter?

Comment: Examples e.g. on Wikipedia show nodes with two non-leaf children: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Huffman_tree_2.svg -- but you may have created a tree with the special properties you describe; in which case follow the debugging steps I described.

Comment: I thought I was traversing down the tree with  tempNode = root->right; . Then the new tempnode would be one node lower than previous.

Comment: See addition. `root->left` never changes.

Comment: "a common way ... array of leaf nodes" - If an array is going to be used, then it's much quicker to simply have an array or vector of code length and code value, indexed by letter. I think the goal here is to use a Huffman tree, not to implement an efficient encoder.